# What does the NIO constraint level do exactly, and how does it affect performance?

Tags: java, constraints, nio, netty

I noticed the following output from the WebSphere (IBM) JDK when I start my server with Netty NIO code.  I am using Netty 3.4.0 FINAL with IBM JDK for WebSphere 6.1.

> Using the autodetected NIO constraint level: 1 (Use better NIO provider for better performance)

So first off I am curious what exactly the constraint level does, I can't seem to find any information on it.  Second I think I can override it by using the statement below:

```
-Djava.nio.channels.spi.constraintLevel=0
```

What is a "better NIO provider" mean - is that saying I need a better JVM - not IBM one I have to use for WebSphere?

Answer (score 2):

Netty constructs a "constraint level" parameter based on the JVM and operating system, using its own algorithm.  You can find the source code for that algorithm [on grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.netty/netty/3.4.0.Alpha1/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/nio/NioProviderMetadata.java#NioProviderMetadata.detectConstraintLevelFromSystemProperties%28%29). From this value, it makes decisions about how to enable certain functionality.

If the algorithm returns a non-zero value, then you get that message.

You *can* override it with the system property you mention, but then you're telling Netty that you know best when it comes to what the system can do, and you may end up with poorer performance than if you leave it alone.

Comment: So I should just leave it be?  My concern is that the performance was degraded, hence the warning, unless I took some kind of action.  I am looking for the best performance, but limited to using IBM WebSphere JDK.

Comment: @BrianYoder: Performance probably will be degraded, compared to a different platform. But it may well still be good enough. You won't know until you try it.